# HDFS file usage

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using Hadoop 2.8.1 and faced some issue about file size.

The command `hdfs dfs -df -h` prints the following result:

```
Size   Used  Available  Use%
4.6 T  3.8 T    861.6 G   82%
```

While `hdfs dfs -du -s -h /` prints this:

```
599.0 G  /
```

What the issue could be about?

Comment: Remove the `-s` operation and see the list of folders its showing & check whether all folders are shown. The same command works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`du -sh` is used to get the summary of a grand total disk usage size of specific directory that's why you only see `/` in output. `du -h` will list all directories